# Check whether pathogen is installed in vimrc

Tags: vim

I would like to check in `.vimrc` whether pathogen is present, and call `pathogen#infect` if it is.

This obviously works:

```
call pathogen#infect()
```

So I'm confident pathogen is properly installed.

But this does not load pathogen:

```
if exists("*pathogen#infect")
    call pathogen#infect()
endif
```

Neither does this:

```
if exists("g:loaded_pathogen")
    call pathogen#infect()
endif
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your check doesn't work because of the autoload mechanism. You could force the autoload by explicitly sourcing it:

```
runtime! autoload/pathogen.vim
if exists("*pathogen#infect")
    call pathogen#infect()
endif
```

But in the end, you probably just want to avoid errors from your .vimrc when Pathogen isn't installed. For that, just silence any resulting errors with `:silent!`:

```
silent! call pathogen#infect()
```

The only downside is that any Pathogen plugin errors would be suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for the problem:)

```
if filereadable(expand("~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim"))
    runtime! autoload/pathogen.vim
    if exists("g:loaded_pathogen")
       execute pathogen#infect()
    endif
endif
```

Comment: In case pathogen is not installed in ~/.vim, for example by default on MS Windows :  if !empty(findfile('autoload/pathogen.vim', &rtp)) ...